# Difference between run the Flask and Django application

Tags: python, flask

I don't understand why if I want to run Flask application I need

```
(venv) $ export FLASK_APP=microblog.py
(venv) $ flask run
```

But if I want to run Django application I only

```
(venv) $ python manage.py runserver
```

without `export DJANGO_APP=microblog.py`
Why? Why I need the export app in the first case, but in the second case I don't need?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem: When you write the command `flask run` in the console, how does flask know which file to run?

Solution: Thats why we use `export FLASK_APP=microblog.py`

It is setting the FLASK_APP (an internal flask variable) value to microblog.py

It tells flask to use microblog.py as start-up file for the application when you run flask via `flask run` command.

If you decide not to do so, then when you run `flask run`, then there is no way for flask to know which file to run. Now you could run the application using `python filename.py` instead of `flask run`

So `python microblog.py` in your case.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, Django and Flask are different frameworks. There's no reason why the commands to start them should be the same.

You need to export `FLASK_APP` [to tell flask which app to run](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/cli/#application-discovery).

Doing `export FLASK_APP=microblog.py` sets an environment variable `FLASK_APP`. The `flask` application can then read this variable from the environment and use it to run the application.

In Python you can access environment variables from [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ), or use the [`os.getenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv) method:

```
import os
flask_app = os.getenv('FLASK_APP')
```

If you use the `django-admin` command, you need to export `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in a similar way:

```
$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yourproject.settings
$ django-admin runserver
```

However with Django, you usually use `runserver` with `manage.py` instead of `django-admin`. The `manage.py` is specific to your project and sets the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable if it hasn't been set already:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourproject.settings")
```

Therefore you don't need to export `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` when using `manage.py`.

Answer (score 1):

From a source code prospective, seems that the FLASK_APP variabile is used for understand which flask app run in a 'multi-flask-app' environment.

Is necessary only if the `app_name` from the source is not present.

The FLASK_APP env variable is used only into the `find_best_app` method of the cli.py file of the flask framework.

Answer (score 1):

Simply in your project, you don't need something like export FLASK_APP=microblog.py unless you want environment variables

```
from flask import jsonify,Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/<Your Route>/<string:<Your Param>>")
def main(<Your Param>):

    //DO LOGIC HERE 
    data =[{'TestData1' : "" ,<YOUR OUTPUT>}]

    return jsonify(data), 200

app.run(debug=False,host="0.0.0.0",port=<PORT YOU WANT TO HOST>)
```